# Is potential difference is sufficient for charge/current flow?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, charge

Suppose there are two points A and B. A is having fewer electrons than B. That is,it is positive with respect to B.If these two points are connected by conductive wire will the current flow? If this theory is correct explain the following experiment. 
"***A Batteries positive terminal and earths ground is connected by a conductive wire through a blub. Then why the bulb is not glowing?*** Why current is not flowing in this scenario?"

Comment: Because the *total* charge of the battery is always zero (i.e. the number of electrons is the same as the number of "holes". If the electron will "run away" from it to the earth, the battery will remain very positive, which is not physical. Or in short - the circuit is open and there is no potential difference.

Comment: You need the negative end of the battery connected properly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Current *is* flowing, but an incandescent bulb glows not because of current, but because of *heat*. There isn't enough current flowing for the filament to get hot enough for it to emit visible light.

Comment: what if it is an LED which can glow at microamps/milliamps?

Comment: Then it is reverse biased.

Comment: why? and how it woks?

Comment: Because it's not glowing. Reverse biased LEDs pass almost no current.

Comment: Okay forget about LED :P. Imagine a hypothetical bulb which is able to glow in milli/micro amps.I think I can see the light right now. am i right?

Comment: Only if enough current is flowing to allow it to glow.